# Difference OnInit and OnLoad in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I had an interview a week ago and one of the questions was what the difference was between OnInit and Onload in ASP.NET? I had no clue and I don't find any simple answers on the net so can someone explain shortly and simple what the difference is between both? (What I found was that the difference was somehting in the lifecycle).

Comment: Don't feel too bad. I regularly conduct interviews for "senior" ASP.NET developers, and only very few of them understand the page lifecycle.

Comment: Yeah I know (and I just started my "carreer" 5 months ago) but I had something about this question that I've should known the answer. And after the interview I realy wanted to understand the difference between both but I couldn't find a simple answer on the net, until now ;) ty

Comment: Page/MasterPage/Control lifecycle makes me cry :(

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to read up on the [ASP.NET page lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).

`OnInit` happens earlier in the lifecycle - view state changes have not been done yet and tracking of it has not been turned on.

Comment: Ok that tells more, but I don't get why I should do something before the view state changes are loaded. Can you give an example? That would make it more simple for me to understand why it's usefull..

Comment: @daageu - If you need to initialize a control, you should do that here. This is also the best time to recreate dynamic controls - otherwise changes to their viewstate will not get reflected automatically.

Answer (score 29):

`OnInit` (the `Init` event) happens after all controls have been initialized, but before `ViewState` tracking is enabled. It's called bottom-up (the `Init` events for child controls are called before their parent's `Init` event).

`Init` is a good place to add dynamic controls to your page or user control (though it's not a requirement). If you can, then those controls will have their `ViewState` restored automatically during postbacks (see below). It's a risky place to set control properties, though, because they can be overwritten by incoming `ViewState`. `Init` is the right place to set `ViewStateUserKey`, which can help protect your site from one-click attacks. You would also call `RegisterRequiresControlState()` from there, if you're using control state.

Right after the `Init` event, each control enables `ViewState` tracking, so any changes to a control's properties after that will be reflected in `ViewState`.

The next events at the page level are `InitComplete` and `PreLoad`, neither of which is visible at the control level. During a postback, incoming `ViewState` is restored into controls between `InitComplete` and `PreLoad`.

Then comes the `Load` event, which happens for both controls and the page. `Load` is called first at the parent level, and then for any child controls. A master page behaves like a control on a page with regard to event ordering.

Comment: Perfect thank you! I found some information about the life cycle from Init to Onload but much more difficult discribed than this.

Answer (score 5):

`Page_Init` is raised before `Page_Load`. `Page_Init` is a good place for code that you want executed before you process further such as attaching event handlers to the load event.

**it is better not to access controls in this event because you aren't guaranteed they have been created**.

**The Page_Load is a good place to store code where you initialize values and any controls specific to the page because you know at this point the controls exist and are available.**

You will place a lot more code in Page_Load than you will in Page_Init for the majority of your apps

Comment: Instead of a link, why not also post a summary of the page, so not everyone has to click through?

Comment: Thanks for the summary! Helped alot.

Answer (score 0):

Both these methods of [Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.aspx) class are invoked by ASP.NET. `OnInit()` method raises the `Init` event and `OnLoad()` method raises the `Load` event.

Comment: Yeah I knew this but I want to understand the difference between both and an example of when I should use Init and when OnLoad